# Qual a origem da expressão "pagar o pato"?

Tags: origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas

"Pagar o pato" é uma expressão conhecida no Brasil. Tão conhecida que, em 2015, houve uma campanha chamada "[Não Vou Pagar o Pato](http://www.naovoupagaropato.com.br)", contra o aumento de impostos.

Eu não me lembrava o significado da expressão, mas buscando no Google parece ter a ver com "ser responsabilizado por algo que não cometeu".

Por fim, gostaria de saber: de onde vem essa expressão? Estou curioso sobre os patos desta história :)

Comment: É porque o pato vinha cantando alegremente,  qüem, qüem quando se encontrou com o marreco. [piada, não leve a sério]

Comment: Também se diz em Portugal, portanto deve ser coisa antiga. Mas, da memória das ocasiões em que ouvi, quem paga o pato não tem de ser "inocente"; pode simplesmente não ser o único "culpado", mas só ele é que paga.

Comment: Novamente, da minha memória", poderia ser explicado por um grupo de amigos roubar um pato, ou comer um num restaurante, e depois só um é que, involuntariamente, pagava a despesa toda. Isto há de tar relacionado com o *soube-me a pato* = 'alguém, inesperadamente, me pagou a refeição'. Agora, porquê pato? Galinha, cabrito ou leitão serviria o mesmo propósito. Já vem num dicionário de 1873.

Comment: Para mim, quem paga o pato é apenas quem paga ou se ferra, não necessariamente o culpado ou inocente ou até envolvido naquilo.  Mas, aparentemente há mais de um significado por aí: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pagar-o-pato/33206.

Comment: O voto negativo nesta pergunta é tão absurdo, que me pergunto se foi engano. Ou então alguém suspeita que lhe deste um voto negativo e quis vingar-se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quanto à origem de ***pagar o pato***, a resposta curta é: não se sabe ao certo; a única certeza é que a expressão já era usada por volta de 1550 em Portugal e em Espanha—*pagar el pato*. *Pagar el pato de la boda*, que o [Ciberdúvidas (2014)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pagar-o-pato/33206) parece tomar como a expressão original, é uma variante tardia. As expressões portuguesa e castelhana hão de ter a mesma origem, pelo que vou usar material de ambas as línguas.

### Primeiros exemplos conhecidos e significado

Em Portugal o mais antigo exemplo conhecido é de [Francisco Sá de Miranda (1481-1558)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1_de_Miranda), numa carta em verso  muito crítica do novo Portugal ([texto integral aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=SNwFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=%22he%20pagar%20o%20pato%22&source=bl&ots=4OZ2qWnC0Z&sig=ACfU3U1wzRLj1yY-RbnWxrAw4CM3wTdQ5w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXusrZzdvyAhV5BWMBHeEPDacQ6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=%22he%20pagar%20o%20pato%22&f=false)); vindo ele a falar das festas da alta sociedade, com os seus luxos orientais , “que preço nam tem igual”, diz:

> Onde se ha de lançar tanto,
> Aquillo he pagar o pato.

Os primeiros exemplos conhecidos são importantes no estudo da origem duma expressão, porque nós queremos ter uma ideia de quando é ela aparece, e além disso poderão dar-nos dicas acerca das circunstâncias que a originaram. Infelizmente, neste caso o sentido exato da expressão não é claro. Fica-se com a ideia que alguém tem de pagar aquelas extravagâncias, mas não é sequer óbvio que haja alguém a pagar pelo que não fez.

Os primeiros exemplos em castelhano são igualmente obscuros. *Pagar el pato* vem já neste [Libro de Refranes de 1549](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gn315iBjo7EC&pg=PP111&dq=%22pagar%20el%20pato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibg6_n2NvyAhVqzoUKHf1QAu0Q6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22pagar%20el%20pato%22&f=false); sem qualquer explicação, mas sugerindo que a expressão era já nesta altura bem conhecida em Espanha. Temos a expressão também na [Farsa del molinero (cerca de 1525-47)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=G6dFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA107&dq=%22que%20hacen%20pagar%20el%20pato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEzoP299HyAhUP8BQKHd4bDCkQ6AEwAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22que%20hacen%20pagar%20el%20pato%22&f=false) e em [Las coplas del vil (antes de 1552)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=iWrLfgsKA78C&pg=PA319&dq=%22no%20querria%20pagar%20el%20pato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC-KuS99HyAhWHDGMBHVHLBnEQ6AEwAnoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22no%20querria%20pagar%20el%20pato%22&f=false). Este último eu li com atenção com a ajuda do dicionário: Uma donzela tenta seduzir um pastor, para que venha ter com ela, e ele vai-lhe dando negas. Às tantas ela diz-lhe (tradução minha), “comerás, pois te convido, e de mim te faço o prato”, e ele responde, “Não queria pagar o pato”.

Também aqui não se vislumbra o sentido atual da expressão (e quem quiser que se entenda com a [Farsa del molinero](https://books.google.pt/books?id=G6dFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA107&dq=%22que%20hacen%20pagar%20el%20pato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEzoP299HyAhUP8BQKHd4bDCkQ6AEwAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22que%20hacen%20pagar%20el%20pato%22&f=false)). Mas o sentido já fica claro em séculos mais recentes, até porque entretanto aparecem os dicionários. Neste [Diccionario de la lengua castellana de 1737](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_CHEd9t6dY4C&pg=PA78&dq=%22pagar%20el%20pato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl3dbI5dvyAhVbDWMBHUnDCc4Q6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22pagar%20el%20pato%22&f=false), o significado já é o de pagar por coisa que outros fizeram, e é o que encontramos nos dicionários brasileiros e vários portugueses de hoje (Houaiss (2002), [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/pato), [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pato/), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/pato), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pato)).

Nos dicionários antigos de português, o significado é um nadinha mais abrangente, que é o que eu conhecia: pagar pelos que os outros fizeram ou pagar só eu por algo que eu e outros fizemos em conjunto (conta num restaurante, por exemplo); vejam o [Moraes Silva de 1789](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KvFj2p9f8RgC&pg=RA1-PA170&lpg=RA1-PA170&dq=%22pagar%20o%20dano%20ou%20perda%22&source=bl&ots=-3Xet17gNd&sig=ACfU3U0ThTTd1GbXbFrbHbL1cuUdQaJBWA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw-sPI69vyAhUjzoUKHcpDAbgQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22pagar%20o%20dano%20ou%20perda%22&f=false) ou esta [Collecção de proverbios publicada no Rio de Janeiro em 1848](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lttWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA141&dq=%22pagar%20o%20pato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2j7fN19DyAhXR4uAKHcpvAdkQ6AEwE3oECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22pagar%20o%20pato%22&f=false). Na verdade, a diferença é ligeira e variações destas são naturais. O significado duma expressão existe na cabeça de quem a diz e quem a ouve, e as circunstâncias a propósito de que são usadas podem variar no tempo e no espaço.

### Conjeturas sobre a origem

**Jogos antigos.** O historiador espanhol Aureliano Fernandez-Guerra sugeriu na [Biblioteca de autores españoles de 1859](https://books.google.pt/books?id=UVOhRsuRkf8C&pg=PA411&dq=%22pagar%20el%20pato%20llevar%20alguno%20el%20castigo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjewt6K89vyAhVChRoKHWfHArQQ6AEwAnoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22pagar%20el%20pato%20llevar%20alguno%20el%20castigo%22&f=false) que o dizer foi “tomado acaso de algun juego ó diversion”. Variantes elaboradas desta hipótese aparecem em português em dois sites, este [Dicionário Popular](https://www.dicionariopopular.com/pagar-o-pato/) e este [Expressões Populares](https://expressoespopulares.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/pagar-o-pato-a-origem/) (onde a hipótese é transformada em certeza), que o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pagar-o-pato/33206) achou por bem citar. Estas variantes descrevem com algum pormenor um jogo que se praticaria antigamente em Portugal, e que envolve um pato; quem perdesse tinha de pagar literalmente o pato. Infelizmente, à semelhança de muitas explicações de origens de expressões publicadas por aí, nenhum dos sites apresenta qualquer evidência que esse jogo alguma vez tivesse existido.

**Conexão judaica.** Casiodoro de Reina na “Amoestacion al lector” da sua
[tradução espanhola da Biblia (1573)](https://archive.org/details/labibliaqveeslos00rein/page/n33/mode/2up?q=%22como%20los%20vocablos%22) comenta que os judeus diziam que tinham a Tora e o Pacto (com Deus), e que os espanhóis, não compreendendo estas palavras, zombavam dizendo que os judeus adoravam uma *tora* (’toura, vaca’) pintada na sinagoga e que “del Pacto sacaron por refran contra ellos [os judeus], Aqui pagareys el pato”. Deste “sacaron” (’sacaram, tiraram’), não sei se ele está a dizer que a locução nasceu aqui ou se simplesmente os espanhóis usaram ou adaptaram uma locução já existente, mas [El Refranero General Español de 1877](https://books.google.pt/books?id=BH8DYTgzyE8C&pg=PA108&dq=%22verdadero%20origen%20de%20esta%20locucion%20proverbial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjciLrV-9vyAhVDAmMBHWhRCM4Q6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22verdadero%20origen%20de%20esta%20locucion%20proverbial%22&f=false) não duvida que esta é “a verdadeira origem desta locução”.

**Anedota medieval.** O filólogo João Ribeiro ([Frases Feitas, 1908 (edição de 2009)](https://www.academia.org.br/sites/default/files/publicacoes/arquivos/frases_feitas_-_joao_ribeiro_-para_internet.pdf)) não vê mérito nesta hipótese da conexão judaica e diz que, “ao que presumimos”, a origem está numa anedota incluída por Poggio Bracciolini (1380-1459) nas suas *Facetiae* (’facécias’). Encontrei uma [tradução em inglês das Facetiae](https://elfinspell.com/PoggioSecond1.html) (procurem “Of a Countryman Who Had a Goose for Sale”). Um rapagão tinha um ganso para vender. Uma mulher pergunta quanto custa, e ele responde que era só um “coito”. Vão para a casa dela, e dois coitos depois ele alega que o ganso ainda não está pago: o primeiro coito não valeu porque a mulher estava por cima; o segundo, com ele por cima, foi só para ficarem quites. Nisto chega o marido, e ela diz que lhe queria preparar um manjar, que o rapaz acordara vender o ganso por 20 soldos e agora exigia 22. O marido diz que não iam perder o jantar por uma ninharia, e pagou o ganso ao rapaz.

Comment: Que excelente pesquisa! Nunca imaginei que a expressão pudesse ser tão antiga. Uma pena que muitas origens se perdem ao longo do tempo, mas ao menos rendem boas histórias.

Comment: @Rafael, bem verdade. Ainda há (artigo do Ciberdúvidas) a história de três amigos que comeram um pato numa hospedaria, e depois fizeram um grande cena, insistindo cada um em pagar a conta toda , até que o hospedeiro, possivelmente para poder ir dormir, pagou ele a conta. Esta história foi publicado só em 1879, por isso não tive para estar a alongar a resposta com ela.

Comment: @Rafael, eliminei aquela última observação da Introdução da tradução inglesa das *Facetiae*, que edições impressas tinham, "nas palavras do autor", transbordado por toda a Europa onde se compreendia latim. Isto seria muito relevante, mas é duvidoso: primeira edição impressa conhecida é posterior à morte do autor.